# CsvHelper - How to Create a CsvClassMap for a Column Not in the Class

Tags: csvhelper

How do I add a column to my CsvClassMap for a property that doesn't exist in my class?

### Class to Write to a File

```cs
public class Customer {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### CsvClassMap

```cs
public sealed class CustomerMap : CsvClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap() {
        Map(r => r.ID).Index(1)
        Map(r => r.Name).Index(2)
        //need a column called Rec ID that is simple concatenation of ID and Name
        Map(r => ???).Index(0).Name("Rec ID")
    }
}
```

### Desired CSV Output

> Rec ID,ID,Name
>
> 1Bob,1,Bob

---

[GitHub Issue Reference](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/678#issuecomment-301855364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing to CSV, I prefer to manually map objects to a class that perfectly matches my expected columns. It's very flexible, explicit, and no more code than needed to write a CSV class map. In your case it would look something like this

```
var customerRows = customers.Select(c => new {RecID = c.ID + c.Name, c.ID, c.Name });
```

Then you would write customerRows to the CSV.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  That is definitely a valid approach.  I'll have to give that some thought.  I've already started down this path though.

Comment: After thinking about it and implementing it with maps and converters I think your approach is better.  I ended up with a lot of classes.  With a select it would have been just one big linq select.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a lot of classes. In fact, a lot of times it can make for cleaner code.